# Scrollbar inside flexbox keeps "bouncing" (IE11)

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow, flexbox

I am currently working on a dialog window that is positioned over the whole page and consists of 3 parts - the head part, the content part and the foot part.
The dialog window itself has a maximum-height.

The head and foot parts have a fixed height.
The content part wraps around its content and grows / shrinks with it.
If the content exceeds the maximum-height of the dialog window, it should become scrollable.

The whole thing is built with a flexbox and works just fine in FF and Chrome. Unfortunately the client needs to have it working in IE11 aswell, but this causes a to me unknown bug - Everytime the user moves the mouse in to / out of the content (which should be scrollable), the container breaks out of its overflow and bounces back in.

I could imagine that flexbox and scrollbars don't get along with each other well in IE11 - but I couldn't find any related issues in the web.

Is such an issue already known?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It helps if we can reproduce the problem. Please post your code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Well, I can not reproduce the problem by myself. But anyway here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/k9hcdtuv/3/

Comment: Without being able to reproduce the problem there's not much we can do. However, there are numerous IE11 flexbox bugs (*flexbugs*). Take a look through here for possible guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276